# Emoticons based sentiment

Tags: r, qdap

I am working on sentiments and would like to replace the emoticons with words expressing the mood of the emoticon using **qdap** in R.

Can someone help me how to do it. I will further use the output to get the overall sentiment of the text.

Comment: Please post what you have tried yet.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
text <- "I like :) chicken but not beef :("

library(qdapDictionaries)
mgsub(as.character(emoticon[[2]]), as.character(emoticon[[1]]), text)

## "I like Smile chicken but not beef Sad"
```

Comment: PS the columns in the `emoticon` dictionary are stored as factor.  This has been changed to character in the del version and once it goes to CRAN `as.character` will not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly and you are talking about plain emoticons, you can just do a pattern match and replace

```
R>  text = c(":)", ":(")
R> gsub(":)", "happy", text)
[1] "happy" ":("
```

Comment: thanks , but when applying this with other gsub commands it throws an error